# Remove first line of duplicated lines on first column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a large csv file with a structure similar to this:

```
334050049049426,2018-11-06T20:21:56.591Z,xxx,gdl-qns28-1540279057144
334050049049426,2018-11-06T21:32:47.431Z,xxx,gdl-qns19-1540278993723
334090015032064,2018-11-06T22:22:31.247Z,xxx,gdl-qns15-1540279009813
334090015032064,2018-11-07T01:44:11.442Z,xxx,gdl-qns25-1540279437614
334090015032064,2018-11-07T03:57:18.911Z,xxx,gdl-qns28-1540279710160
334050069888299,2018-11-07T03:32:12.899Z,xxx,gdl-qns29-1540279367769
334050069888299,2018-11-07T03:58:15.475Z,xxx,mgc-qns20-1540281468455
```

I need to be able to remove the first line found of duplicated values from the first column so for example lines number 1, 3 and 6 needs to be remove.

Comment: Better use a tool designed to process csv, not the shell directly.

Comment: Are duplicated lines always consecutive? Are there always at least two lines with the same first field? (in that case `awk -F, 'seen[$1]++'` would be enough).

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to keep line 4 even though it's a duplicate?

Comment: I want to keep all duplicates, except the first one found, so for example if the first column has 4 duplicated values, take out the first row of that group and leave the remaining 3.  By the way, all duplicates are always consecutive and there will be at least two duplicated lines with the same first field.

Answer (score 1):

try below `awk` if there is no line having unique first column at all.

```
awk -F, 'pre==$1 { print; next }{ pre=$1 }' infile
```

Or below instead in general case:

```
awk -F, 'pre==$1 { print; is_uniq=0; next }
                 # print when current& previous lines' 1st column were same
                 # unset the 'is_uniq=0' variable since duplicated lines found

         is_uniq { print temp }
                 # print if previous line ('temp' variable keep a backup of previous line) is a 
                 # uniq line (according to the first column)

                 { pre=$1; temp=$0; is_uniq=1 }
                 # backup first column and whole line into 'pre' & 'temp' variable respectively
                 # and set the 'is_uinq=1' (assuming might that will be a uniq line)

END{ if(is_uniq) print temp }' infile
    # if there was a line that it's uniq and is the last line of input file, then print it
```

same script with comments free:

```
awk -F, 'pre==$1 { print; is_uniq=0; next }
         is_uniq { print temp }
                 { pre=$1; temp=$0; is_uniq=1 }
END{ if(is_uniq) print temp }' infile
```

**Note:** this assumes your input file `infile` is sorted on its first field, if that's not then you will need to pass sorted file into with

```
awk ... <(sort -t, -k1,1 infile)
```

Comment: There is no need to do any check on the END. If the line is repeated, print it. If it is uniq, there are no more lines to make it repeated, so print anyway.

Comment: A sort will change the original ordering of the file (that may be needed or not depending on use).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the csv has a well behaved format (no commas or newlines inside quoted fields, no double quoted `"` (`""`), etc) you can use this:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{seen1[$1]++;next};seen1[$1]==1||seen2[$1]++
            {print(NR,$0)}' infile infile
```

The only way to know if a line is repeated at any place of the file is to get a count of times a line is repeated. That is done with `seen1`. Then, if the line has a count of 1 (no repeats) or if it has already been seen (this second scan of the file) (done with `seen2`)  print it.

If the file is **sorted** by the first field use @devWeek solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
1,a
2,b
2,c
3,d
3,e
3,f
4,g
4,h
5,i
```

We want to remove the "2,b", "3,d" and "4,g" lines:

```
perl -F, -anE '
    push $lines{$F[0]}->@*, $_ 
  } END { 
    for $key (sort keys %lines) {
        shift $lines{$key}->@* if (scalar($lines{$key}->@*) > 1); # remove the first
        print join "", $lines{$key}->@*;
    }
' file
```

```
1,a
2,c
3,e
3,f
4,h
5,i
```